# Change level of PDF "List of ..." bookmarks without affecting their TOC levels

Tags: bookmarks

**Problem:** I am trying to create a lists bookmark under which my list of tables, figures, reaction schemes etc can go so that the PDF bookmarks do not look cluttered with just a long list expanded. This is how my thesis document bookmarks look presently:

[image]

Using `\pdfbookmark[0]{Front Matter}{FMbookmark}` and manually changing the PDF bookmark levels of the "Front Matter" sections worked as intended but I am running into an issue with the lists, presumably because the lists are included in the TOC.

**What I have tried:** The MWE shows what I tried, namely using the `*` versions of the LOF, LOT and manually creating TOC entries and PDF Bookmark entries but the bookmarks are still being generated based upon the TOC and looks like this:

[image]

I am not sure how to square the issue of wanting the TOC entries of the lists to be at one level and for the bookmarks to be at a different level whilst still automatically generating bookmarks from the TOC entries with `hyperref`.

**What I would like:** Ideally, I want the PDF bookmarks to still be generated by `hyperref` automatically (main body, appendices etc) and the TOC entries for the lists to still show as chapters (i.e. be in bold with no `\ldots`) but for the lists section bookmarks to all be under a lists heading although I am open to alternatives

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{contentsbookmark}
\tableofcontents*
\newpage

\pdfbookmark[0]{Lists}{listsbookmark}
\pdfbookmark[1]{List of Figures}{lofbookmark}

\listoffigures*
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\newpage

\pdfbookmark[1]{List of Tables}{lotbookmark}

\listoftables* 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\newpage

\chapter{Test}
\begin{table} \caption{Test} \end{table}
\begin{figure} \caption{Test} \end{figure}
\newpage
\begin{table} \caption{Test} \end{table}
\begin{figure} \caption{Test} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have looked through the automatically generated similar questions and after a search could not find anything that answers this, if this is a duplicate of a question that I could not find then I would appreciate a comment pointing to it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark} %not required but makes it faster
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[0]{Lists}{listsbookmark}

\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@chapter{1}
\makeatother
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@chapter{0}
\makeatother


\chapter{Test}
\begin{table} \caption{Test} \end{table}
\begin{figure} \caption{Test} \end{figure}
\newpage
\begin{table} \caption{Test} \end{table}
\begin{figure} \caption{Test} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]